# Query mysql for post and comments system

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter for make a post and comments system. I did all the querys but I don't know how get the comments in the table post_comment. This is my query for take all the post shared. Thank you for the help.

```
function get_post_profile($user_id,$limit) {
        $this->db->select('post_user.user_id,post_user.id_post_shared,post_shared.post_text,users.name,users.surname,users.id');
        $this->db->join('post_shared', 'post_shared.id_post = post_user.id_post_shared');
        $this->db->join('users','users.id = post_user.user_id');
        $this->db->where('post_user.user_id',$user_id);
        $this->db->order_by('post_user.id_post_shared','DESC');
        $this->db->limit($limit);
        $query = $this->db->get('post_user');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

users_table

```
id | name | surname |
1    jhon    Smith
2    Sally   Dunk
```

post_user table

```
id_post_shared | user_id |
      1             1
```

post_share table

```
id_post | post_text
   1      Hello guys
```

post_comment table

```
comment_text | id_post | id_user
   Hello!        1          2
```

Comment: Can you do a `$this->db->last_query()'` after `$query = $this->db->get('post_user');` and tell us the query you've got, so we know where we went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and reply:

```
$this->select('post_comment.comment_text, post_comment.id_post, post_comment.id_user')->join('post_share', 'post_share.id_post = post_comment.id_post')->join('users', 'users.id = post_comment.id_user')->get('post_comment');
```

**EDIT**

```
function get_comments(){
    $data   = array();
    $posts  = array();
    $posts  = $this->db->select('id_post as post_id, post_text', false)->order_by('id_post', 'desc')->get('post_share', 10)->result_array();   #get first 10 posts
    if( is_array( $posts ) && count( $posts ) > 0 ){
        foreach( $posts as $key=>$each ){
            ## gather the comments for the posts ###
            $comments   = array();
            $comments   = $this->db->select('comment_text, id_user')->where('id_post', $each['post_id'])->get('post_comment')->result_array();
            if( is_array( $comments ) && count( $comments ) ){
                $posts[$key]['comments']    = $comments;
            }
        }
    }
    return $posts;
}
```

**EDIT 1**

```
if( isset( $posts ) && is_array( $posts ) && count( $posts ) > 0 ){
    foreach( $posts as $key=>$each ){
        echo "Post id :".$each['post_id']." Post txt: ".$each['post_text']."<br>";
        if( isset( $each['comments'] ) && is_array( $each['comments'] ) && count( $each['comments'] ) ){
            foreach( $each['comments'] as $subKey=>$subEach ){
                echo "Comment Txt :".$subEach['comment_text']."<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working because the result is not like I'm looking for. I would like have the post shared with all the comments example like facebook.

Comment: Try the above function and reply

Comment: I think this one is right, but sorry for the question how can i print posts and comments? with the normal for each doesn't work. Thank you very much

Comment: I'd print the posts correctly, but how can i print the comments? i did it like that for the post:

foreach ($result as $post => $each) { echo $each['post_id']; }

Comment: Now try once the edited part in your view and change the code as applicable.

Comment: Yes thank you so much you help me so much :) but can you syas me how can i print the comments? I change the query with my field but all work fine, only the comments i can't see it. :)

Comment: Were you able to print the comments or not?@fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

Add `LEFT JOIN` to your  `post_comment`

```
$this->db->select('post_user.user_id,post_user.id_post_shared,
post_shared.post_text,users.name,users.surname,users.id,post_comment.comment_text');
        $this->db->join('post_shared', 'post_shared.id_post = post_user.id_post_shared');
        $this->db->join('users','users.id = post_user.user_id');
        $this->db->join('post_comment ','users.id = post_comment .id_user','LEFT');
        $this->db->where('post_user.user_id',$user_id);
        $this->db->order_by('post_user.id_post_shared','DESC');
        $this->db->limit($limit);
        $query = $this->db->get('post_user');
```

third parameter in the call is to specify the type of join `join('table','relation','join type')`

Comment: I think should be used Union right? Your query is not right thank you the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT a.*,b.id,b.name,b.surname,c.id_post_shared,c.user_id,d.id_post,d.post_text            
        FROM post_comment a, users_table b, post_user c,post_share d 
        WHERE b.id = c.user_id 
        AND b.id = $user_id 
        AND c.id_post_shared = d.id_post 
        AND d.id_post = a.id_post";

$result = $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();

echo $result[0]['comment_text'];
```

Comment: Is better, but still not complete, because I don't want select the comments by id user but I'll select all the posts of the users with the relative comments.

Comment: what do you mean, you said you wanna select the comments in the table post_comment....